# kotlin android Realm DB create a foreign key (Linking Objects)

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I have 2 tables student and a teacher.

The student table has 3 fields, name, roll_no, subjects.
Roll_no being primary key.

Another table named marks with 4 fields subject ID, subject name, subject score and roll_no
roll_no field will be a foreign key.

How to create a relation like the marks table refers as a foreign key to student table's roll_no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Realm doesn't have foreign keys.

Long answer: Realm wants you to think about your data as objects, instead of tables and links (https://realm.io/docs/kotlin/latest/#relationships).

Assuming roll_no is kind of like a student_id - you could model your data like this:

```kotlin
open class Student(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = "",
    var markedSubjects: RealmList<MarkedSubject> = RealmList()
): RealmObject()

open class MarkedSubject(
    var subject: Subject? = null,
    var mark: Int? = null
): RealmObject()
```